# Como fazer o código não pegar o ASCII Code de uma variavel?

Tags: c#

Estou tendo um problema ao tentar somar números que estão em uma variavel, porque está pegando o ASCII Code dos mesmos.

Como eu faço para pegar diretamente o número que está dentro de uma variavel?

```
string bin = "1001001";
string final = "";
for (int i = 0; i < bin.Length; i++)
{
    int j = bin[i];
    final += Math.Pow(j * 10, bin.Length - i);
}
Console.WriteLine(final);
```

Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/tGXw5a).

Por exemplo, vamos dizer que `i` tem o valor `1`, o certo seria ele pegar o `0` de `bin[1]`, multiplicar por 10 e elevar a 6 potencia, do qual daria 0. Mas o código está pegando o `bin[1]` e o representando como 48, que seria o valor do mesmo na ASCII Table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode fazer a conversão de char para string, assim você consegue pegar o real valor e depois converter para inteiro

```
int j=int.Parse(bin[i].ToString());
```

Answer (score 4):

O ASCII tem uma característica de que os dígitos estão em ordem, começando pelo `'0'` e terminando no `'9'`. Sendo assim, o valor ASCII do `'0'` é 0x30, o `'1'` é 0x31, etc., até o `'9'` sendo 0x39.

Por consequência, para obter o valor numérico do dígito tendo o caractere, basta subtrair `'0'` dele:

```
for (int i = 0; i < bin.Length; i ++) {
    int j = bin[i] - '0';
    final += Math.Pow(j * 10, bin.Length - i);
}
```

Mas normalmente se usa um outro expediente para analisar sequências de dígitos e transformá-las em números:

```
for (int i = 0, final = 0; i < bin.Length; i ++) {
    int j = bin[i] - '0';
    final = final * 10 + j;
}
```

Isso evita usar o `Math.Pow()`, que é muito mais caro que uma multiplicação inteira.